# Django forms.Choicefield get selected Choice

Tags: python, django, django-forms, choicefield

I need to get the selected Value of a `forms.Choicefield` for an if/else statement which produces another `forms.Choicefield` based on the selected Value

```
forms.py:

class ReceiverForm(forms.Form):
receivers = forms.ChoiceField(choices=db_mails(), required=True, label='Receivers')

if db_certs(<- selected value from receivers ChoiceField ->):
    print "cert found"
    encryption = forms.ChoiceField(choices=EncryptionChoiceAll, initial='smime_mail', required=True, label='Encryption')
else:
    print "no cert found"
    encryption = forms.ChoiceField(choices=EncryptionChoiceNoCert, initial='smime_mail', required=True, label='Encryption')
```

`db_mails()` and `db_certs(mail)` are working as expected

Is there a way to achieve what i need in forms.py or am I totally wrong with the design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the form is built and you specify the choice list, you have no way to know which value is selected, as:

1. You create an instance of the form class
2. This instance is used to create the view (On a GET request). The user can modify the selection
3. He submits the form. For this you create an instance of the class, which is filled with the POST values.

So at the time you create the class you do not have the information.

There are possibilities to have dynamic values in one choice, depending on the other one, but this needs to be done on the client side, when the user changes the selection:

- Use javascript/jquery to update the list of choices depending on the answer. For this, you could have hidden values in the HTML file, and Javascript will update the list from these hidden values.
- If the choice to update is more dynamic (For example a list of towns depending on the post code), you still need to use Javascript, but with Ajax that will send an asynchronous request to the server to get the list and update the choices.

There are plenty of tutorials to do this, and this is not directly linked to Django. As an example:

https://css-tricks.com/dynamic-dropdowns/

Comment: Actually if what you need is to change the choice list of `encryption` depending on the value which selected for `receivers`, that cannot work: when you create the choice list, you still do not know what will be selected when the form is displayed, and there is no way to do it (Except javascript/jquery on the client side, maybe helped with ajax)

Comment: Thank you for pointing things out. I will try to implement it asap. If everything is fine i will check the answer.